# EF + layers, connectionString

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF model in my DAL project, I want the executing project, the web application, to be the one containing the connection string information.

I also would like being able to store the `connectionString` separately from the metadata EF requires.

Is this possible from `web.config` `connectionStrings` alone, or do I need some sort of code-behind to accomplish this? If that's the case, what would be the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EntityConnection` class contains constructor overloads that you can use to pass it in a connection string from your web.config.  Keep in mind though that the connection string that EF wants is not what you typically would store in a connection string in a web.config, it has more than just the SQL Server connection information.  But you can use the [EntityConnectioBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class to help you out with that.